# Coremltools error while converting: "'str' object has no attribute 'decode'"

Tags: python, keras, coremltools

I am trying to use coremltools to convert a keras model to mlmodel.
I am getting the following code:

```
import coremltools
import keras




output_labels = list(range(1, 43))
your_model = coremltools.converters.keras.convert('my_model.h5', input_names=['image'], output_names=['output'],
                                                   class_labels=output_labels, image_input_names='image')

#your_model.author = 'your name'
#your_model.short_description = 'Digit Recognition with MNIST'
#your_model.input_description['image'] = 'Takes as input an image'
#your_model.output_description['output'] = 'Prediction of Digit

your_model.save('your_model_name.mlmodel')
```

This gives me the following error:

```
Users/admin/PycharmProjects/TSR37/venv/bin/python /Users/admin/PycharmProjects/TSR37/coremlconverter.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/admin/PycharmProjects/TSR37/coremlconverter.py", line 9, in <module>
    class_labels=output_labels, image_input_names='image')
  File "/Users/admin/PycharmProjects/TSR37/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/coremltools/converters/keras/_keras_converter.py", line 830, in convert
    use_float_arraytype=use_float_arraytype,
  File "/Users/admin/PycharmProjects/TSR37/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/coremltools/converters/keras/_keras_converter.py", line 607, in _convert_to_spec
    use_float_arraytype=use_float_arraytype,
  File "/Users/admin/PycharmProjects/TSR37/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/coremltools/converters/keras/_keras2_converter.py", line 353, in _convert
    model = _keras.models.load_model(model, custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "/Users/admin/PycharmProjects/TSR37/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/saving.py", line 419, in load_model
    model = _deserialize_model(f, custom_objects, compile)
  File "/Users/admin/PycharmProjects/TSR37/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/saving.py", line 224, in _deserialize_model
    model_config = json.loads(model_config.decode('utf-8'))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

What could be the problem? According to the error message, the problem is with a keras code, not my code, but I don't know.
I am using coremltools 4.0 and python 3.7.9

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it seems to be an issue related to a recent release of version 3.0.0 of h5yp, so either you can use a previous version of h5yp (`pip install tensorflow h5py<3.0.0`) or you can try to remove `.decode('utf-8')` from `tensorflow/python/keras/saving/hdf5_format.py`. I know they are not the answer you are looking for but seems to be the way out. Otherwise you can just wait for an update.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
How do you know that the problem is in the hdf5_format.py? The log says it's the saving.py

Comment: because it is an issue that is being discussed since the h5py release 10 days ago. Here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/44467

Comment: I have to say I didn't tried to do this, just saw this alternative on the github forum

Comment: @DánielAnderle, did it work?

Comment: Yes it did, I have an other, perhaps unrelated problem now, for which I will make a new question